# Webforms and Classic ASP pages IIS7.5

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, iis-7.5

I have a .NET2.0 website running webforms and some classic ASP pages. The pipeline must be Integrated.

I have ASP installed on my webserver :) I also have the application pool running only 32bit applications. However when attempting to access a classic page I receive a 401 unauthorized response.

i.e. http://080080wine.co.nz/wine-plans/wine-plans.asp

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Edit: The exception will occur when adding an

```
<!--#include virtual="/some/path/file.asp" -->
```

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the server since you configured IIS?

Comment: Nope is this required?

Comment: One of the things I read indicated that a reboot could fix this issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses

Comment: could you show code of this file? could you show detailed error info?

Comment: Have you enabled the .asp file extension.  I forget that sometimes.  Here is another SO article that pretty thoroughly discusses this topic.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072048/how-to-enable-asp-classic-in-iis7-5