# html doesn't read my ASP start tag

Tags: html, iis, asp-classic

I have .html file with asp code inside.

```
<html>
<body>
<%
Request.write("hello")
%>
</body>
</html>
```

and this prints
    <% Request.write("hello") %>

I believe ASP is activated because it works when I renamed it to test.asp.

But What I'm trying to do is to encapsulate the asp code inside of html file.

Comment: shouldn't it be `Response.write("hello")`?

Comment: html doesn't "read" anything. IN a properly functioning system. the asp code would NEVER reach the client. you can't expect the remote browser to know what the heck asp code is - the entire universe isn't just microsoft servers and browsers.

Comment: If you want ASP files to be processed when they have a `html` extension you need to add a HTTPHandler into IIS or modify the existing one to work with both `asp` and `html` extensions.

Comment: If you are missing the Handler mappings this will describe how to set them up - [ASP Classic setup issues](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22194273/692942)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP Classic setup issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186052/asp-classic-setup-issues)

Comment: It's perfectly valid to use both server side VBS and client side html within a file with an asp extension - embedding server side code within html is the whole concept of asp.  The .html extension however, is almost always used for files with client side code only, and it's best to leave it that way unless you have a very specific reason not to.

Answer (score 2):

> I believe ASP is activated because it works when I renamed it to test.asp.

Then rename the file to `test.asp`.

By default server-side code is processed in `.asp` files, not `.html` (or any other) files.  Ideally, you don't want to change that as it adds a lot of unnecessary overhead to the web server.  You *can* configure the web server (depending on the web server) to also process other file types, but again it's not recommended.

Additionally, I believe you meant this:

```
Response.write("hello")
```

Writing to the *request* doesn't really make much sense.