# Classic ASP in Windows Server 2019

Tags: iis, asp-classic, windows-server-2019

We have a web app originally built in classic ASP (we are rebuilding in ASP.NET) but we need to migrate to windows 2019 server ASAP.  I have migrated the web app, and configured IIS and we can get the site running on the new server through an entry in Hosts file, however the main body of the website is not being presented.

When we look at the source it states:

> An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.  If you are the system administrator please click [here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=82731) to find out more about this error

When we click the suggested link it opens this URL - [Classic ASP Not Installed by Default on IIS 7.0 and above | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis)[^]

I have checked the server roles and features in server manager and the ALL components in the WEB Server element are installed.  Can someone explain why this is still occurring please?

I also tried changing "managed pipeline mode" in IIS application pool to both Classic and Integrated but same result

Comment: Check the Windows Event Logs. Also enable Failed Request Tracing. I’ll bet it’s a permissions issue w.r.t. AppPoolIdentity.

Comment: The “Managed Pipeline” option only applies to ASP.NET 4.x - it’s not relevant to Classic ASP - nor ASP.NET Core, fwiw.

Comment: This may help - [ASP Classic setup issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22194273)

Comment: One thing to keep in mind that might be tricky if you are migrating the code, is your Application Pool.  If you notice Sessions disappear for "no reason" its likely you didn't set your .NET CLR Version to "No Managed Code"  as Classic does not support Web Gardens etc.

Comment: @Dai - thanks for comments.  I had a look at event logs but there were no "errors" and that along with link to supposed fix in source code is what threw me.  I looked at event log again and a non-error and non-warning entry stated the connection username was not being allowed access to the database.  I fixed that and it worked.  Thanks it was a permissions issue but signs were that it was not.  I would like to update the question as I think it is one for people to know about but question has been closed

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see classic asp error, you need to do some settings in iis:

Please open IIS Manager, select your site, double-click the **ASP** icon and expand "Debugging Properties", then set "Send errors to browser" to True. This will enable sending errors to the browser, since errors are not sent to the browser by default.

[image: ASP]

Then open the **Error Pages** module, select "Edit Feature Settings" from the Actions pane, then select "Detailed errors" and click OK.

[image: error pages]

After completing the above settings, please restart the IIS server.

Comment: thanks this is helpful information.  I have fixed the issue and it was a permissions issue even though indicators were that it was not