# I have already enabled classic asp support on IIS for windows 7, and configured IIS web for classic asp,Yet .asp page is not being displayed?

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp-classic, iis-7.5, iis-6

My .asp page is in the folder named "MyWeb", and "MyWeb" folder is under wwwroot folder which is under inetpub. I also added MIME types in IIS Manager for .asp as application/asp, and for .aspx as application/aspx  I tried it a long but still it is not working. When I go to open that .asp file it is asking for download in IE browser and displaying a blank page in Mozilla Firefox. Please can any body tell me how to solve this issue?

ANSWER=

Issue solved I just changed the setting in IIS Manager set Enable Parent Paths to true and Send Errors To Browser to true and it happened. Localhost Home Page of IIS was displayed and my asp scripts are also running.

Comment: Can you access a .html file in the same folder?

Comment: "http://localhost/MyWeb/Hello.asp", where MyWeb is my folder under wwwroot.

Comment: @AdrianWragg, yes I can access .html file in same folder.

Comment: If you use just "localhost" as url u get the iis page?

Comment: @NiranjanKulkarni Can you go to the Handler Mappings for the site, and check that ASPClassic has been enabled? You're tripping over an IIS security setting, I believe.

Comment: @Alist3r, I am getting this page "http://localhost/SitePages/Home.aspx" on using just localhost.

Comment: @AdrianWragg, I have already installed IIS, and I am using Windows 7. How to go to handler mapping of the site? Would you just tell me what to do next. After IIS gets installed and .asp file is created.

Comment: Maybe you have to run the IIS manager and see if your "site" its correctly added

Comment: @Alist3r, How to run IIS manager? Sorry I am new to classic asp.

Comment: @Alist3r, I ran IIS Manager, but my .asp file is not visible under, Sites --> Default Website --> MyWeb.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable ASP classic in IIS7.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072048/how-to-enable-asp-classic-in-iis7-5)

Comment: @Lankymart, I added script map under "Handler Mappings", as told on respective page but still not working.

Comment: @AdrianWragg, Yes the ASPClassic has been enabled, I saw it just now.

Comment: @NiranjanKulkarni Are you sure you have installed the ASP role? See [Answer by rockspider to How to enable ASP classic in IIS7.5](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13879032/692942)

Comment: @Lankymart, They have given it for windows server 2008, and I am using Window 7. Would be it possible here on my place?

Comment: Guys pardon, I have been trying these for since some couple of days, what should I do to run .asp code on Windows 7 ?

Comment: @NiranjanKulkarni People are trying to help, but we have no idea what you have and haven't done already; hence asking you to check things that you have already checked for yourself. You may find more help on other StackExchange sites instead.

Comment: @AdrianWragg, ok thanks for consideration and guidance

Comment: @NiranjanKulkarni I get the feeling the more I speak to you that you know little to nothing about setting up a website in IIS this also makes me think that you probably don't even have a ASP page in the first place to test (chicken egg scenario). For that reason I'm going to leave this topic alone until you provide so more detailed information in your original question.

Comment: Issue solved I just changed the setting in IIS Manager set Enable Parent Paths to true and Send Errors To Browser to true and it happened. Localhost Home Page of IIS was displayed and my asp scripts are also running.

Answer (score 2):

It possible that you haven't got Classic ASP support installed in IIS. To do this in Windows 7 follow the steps below;

## How to enable Classic ASP support on IIS for Windows 7

### Installing Classic ASP support

1. Goto `Control Panel` -> `Programs and Features`
2. Select from the left navigation bar

   [image: Turn Windows features on or off]
3. From the `Windows Features` dialog expand `Internet Information Services` -> `World Wide Web Services` -> `Application Development Features` and tick the option `ASP` this will also tick `ISAPI Extensions` if not already ticked (see image).

   [image: Windows Features dialog]

### Configuring IIS Web for Classic ASP

1. Open `Administrative Tools` -> `Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager` and select the website you wish to configure.
2. In `Features View` under the `IIS` section select `Handler Mappings` check the existing mappings list that appears for a handler that points to `*.asp` if one doesn't exist select `Add Script Map` from the right hand navigation bar.
3. Fill in the options as per the below image

   [image: ClassicASP Handler]

   > **IMPORTANT** If using 64-bit and want to enable 32-bit support you may wish to use the 32 bit equivalent ISAPI DLL. See [Dee's answer to How to enable ASP classic in IIS7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9072482/692942)
4. Select the `Request Restrictions` button to open `Request Restrictions` dialog. The three images below detail the values that should be configured if not already set.

   [image: Request Restrictions - Mapping]

   [image: Request Restrictions - Verbs]

   [image: Request Restrictions - Access]

Comment: I have already done with this.

Comment: @NiranjanKulkarni Also added detailed instructions on configuring the Classic ASP handler, will update with details of configuring the Application Pool soon.

Comment: Thanks I have went through above steps given, but how to run the asp file in the wwwroot folder?

Comment: @NiranjanKulkarni If the website is running and your Classic ASP page is in the `wwwroot` (or your own configured Home Directory path) you should be able to access it via `http://localhost/<yourpage>.asp`.

Comment: Ya you are 100% right but I am confused why it is not happening by my side.

Comment: Instead I would request you that would you tell me how to execute an .asp page, right from the beginning, suppose if I am having a "Hello World" asp program how to display that hello world? I tried it as given in w3 schools but still not getting it.

Comment: @NiranjanKulkarni If you are still getting a `404 Not Found` try these steps in the `IIS Manager` select your website and bring up the `Basic Settings` and check your `Physical Path` if you are doing this in the `Default Website` that comes pre-installed it will be something like `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot` locate that folder using `Windows Explorer` and check your `.asp` file is there, if not copy it there and try that site address again.

Comment: or, just tell me what I have to do after installing IIS.

Comment: Okay let me clear one thing, Is that compulsion that I have to create a website before writing a .asp program? And if so How should I achieve it step by step?

Comment: @Lankymart, Ya as you said I checked that physical path and that folder resides in default website, I located that folder using windows explorer it is showing me that .asp page. But when I go to open that page browser asks me to open or save file.

Comment: Issue solved I just changed the setting in IIS Manager set Enable Parent Paths to true and Send Errors To Browser to true and it happened. Localhost Home Page of IIS was displayed and my asp scripts are also running.

Comment: @NiranjanKulkarni Glad you finally managed to sort your issue, thing is though parent paths not being enabled would not cause a `HTTP 404 Not Found` if you had `#include` in your ASP code and you needed parent paths you are more likely to get a `HTTP 500 Internal Server Error` so you must have done something else.