# Can't run classic ASP page on Windows 10 even after installing ASP support via "Turn Windows features on or off"

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I get this error:

> An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.
>
> If you are the system administrator please click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis) to find out more about this error.

But I already installed classic ASP support on my IIS; why would I be getting this error? I tried restarting IIS and that didn't help; just in case the error message came from the application itself, I searched for it but didn't find it in the code anywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detailed 500 error message, ASP + IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640526/detailed-500-error-message-asp-iis-7-5)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I have already enabled classic asp support on IIS for windows 7, and configured IIS web for classic asp,Yet .asp page is not being displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22477210/692942)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

to see the classic asp error iis you need to do some settings in iis:

1)open the iis manager and select the classic asp site or the server.

2)Select the Asp feature from the iis.

[image]

3) Expand the Debugging Properties node and set Send Errors To Browser to True.

[image]

4)Go back to the IIS properties and select Error Pages.

[image]

5)Select the Edit Feature Settings from the Action pane and select the Detailed error message radio button.

[image]

Restart the IIS server.

Comment: But please don’t do this on a server that is reachable from the Internet. This is only suitable for test servers (preferably) that are only reachable via trusted networks (not on the Internet).

Comment: You see the duplicate questions? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640526/detailed-500-error-message-asp-iis-7-5) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22477210/692942), your just regurgitating answers already stated there.

Comment: I also noticed when I am browsing on server where site is hosted, it is not showing error in browser, but when browsing from different/ local machine it is showing error.

Comment: For step 2 I didn't have the ASP "button".  To get to that config I scrolled down to Management > clicked on Configuration Editor, opened the section "system.webServer/asp" and switched "scriptErrorSentToBrowser" to "true".

Answer (score 0):

Even if "Send Errors To Browser" to True the displayed error message may not be informative enough. I suggest that inspect your "global.asa" file line by line. Probably you will notice the error.