# ASP (old) exercise on Win 10 - page invoked from .html with server side script

Tags: asp-classic

I am trying to follow along on a Udemy course on how to make an .asp page

name.html has:

```
<body>
    <form action="Name.asp" method="post">
        First Name <input type="text" name="txtFirstName"> <br> 
        Last Name <input type="text" name="txtLastName"> <br>
        <input type="submit" name="btnSayHello" value="Say Hello"> 
    </form>
</body>
```

the name.asp page has the following:

```
<body>
<%
    Dim fn, ln
    fn = Request.Form("txtFirstName")
    ln = Request.Form("txtLastName")
    Response.Write("Hello " " & fn & " " & ln)
%>
</body>
```

when I load the html page in the browser I get basically the exact text of the .asp page
without values processed.

I am a total newbie to IIS but believe I have IIS running on my machine

Comment: ASP unto itself was not available as a tag which is why my subject had "(Old)" in it.....was hoping might still get an answer, sorry / thanks

Comment: You may have IIS running but you need to go into Windows Features and make sure that [Active Server Pages is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22477210/692942).

Comment: You might have IIS installed but are you actually using it?  Did you visit index.html with a url like `http://127.0.0.1/pathto/index.html` or did you open it directly in your browser, so that the location in the address bar begins with `file:/// `? If IIS isn't configured to serve Classic ASP pages then  it usually gives you a 404 page, it doesn't display the raw asp code