# I need help setting up IIS for Debugging ASP

Tags: iis, asp-classic

According to what I have seen on social media, in order for me to set up my computer for writing and debugging Classic ASP, I need to set up IIS a certain way -- which I did -- and then I have to enable ASP by doing the following:

IIS7 - IIS > ASP > Compilation > Debugging Properties > Enable Server-side Debugging

And I am stuck on this.  Please, someone give me an idea of what I need to click on.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To add "ASP" to IIs you need to

1. open control panel.
2. select "Turn Windows features on or off"
3. in the tree check "ASP" under "Internet Information Service"-> World Wide Web Services -> Application Development Features
4. Press OK

after that windows will update the feature and you'll have it in IIS

Comment: Guide on how to do [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22477210/692942).

Comment: You can not step through Classic ASP code like you can for ASP.Net.