# How do I set up IIS to debug classic ASP?

Tags: iis

According to what I have seen on social media, in order for me to set up my computer for writing and debugging Classic ASP, I need to set up IIS a certain way -- which I did -- and then I have to enable ASP by doing the following:

IIS7 - IIS > ASP > Compilation > Debugging Properties > Enable Server-side Debugging

And I am stuck on this. What do I need to click on?

[image]

Comment: Asking the same question multiple times is impolite to whoever answered it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68811744/i-need-help-setting-up-iis-for-debugging-asp

Comment: Exact duplicate: [I need help setting up IIS for Debugging ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68811744/i-need-help-setting-up-iis-for-debugging-asp)

Answer (score 1):

The steps to implement your requirements can be found easily from internet. The reason why you can't see "**ASP**" module in your screenshot is you didn't enable "**ASP**" feature. Please refer to the steps below:

**1.** Open your "**Control Panel**" --> "**Programs**" --> "**Turn Windows feature on or off**".

[image]

**2.** Then you can find "**ASP**" option under "**Internet Information Services**" --> "**World Wide Web Services**" --> "**Application Development Features**" like below screenshot.

[image]

**3.** Just enable "**ASP**" and then go to your IIS manager, choose the site which you want to edit under "**Sites**". Then you can find "**ASP**" module.