# web.config 404 page is not executing

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, iis-7.5

I need to make simple 404 error pages which may have some server side code. for that i have made web.config file as below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="index.asp" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="404.asp" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and 404.asp page has following code

```
404 page   
<%=date%>
```

when i request non existing page then it shows output as

404 page
    <%=date%>

the asp code is sent to browser directly without executing on server side

how can i avoid this

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable ASP classic in IIS7.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072048/how-to-enable-asp-classic-in-iis7-5)

Comment: asp is enabled in iis and other pages are also executing it is error for that 404 page only

Answer (score 0):

change `defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL"` to `defaultResponseMode="Redirect"`. Also use an absolute URL instead of 404.asp (e.g. http://example.com/404.asp)