# How to enable server side VB Script handling on IIS?

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic, iis-10

I have just set up `IIS` on `Win 10`.

I have a page called `hello.asp`:

```
<%@ language="vbscript"%>
<html><body>
<%
response.write("Hello world! - VBScript in IIS")
%>
</body></html>
```

What do I need to do in the IIS Manager to get this page to work?

When I browse to the page I get:

> HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found 
>   The page you are requesting cannot be
>   served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a
>   script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME
>   map.

I don't understand why this handling is not automatically configured when you install IIS.

Comment: It's not enabled by default because of security reasons. The IIS server comes 'pre-secured' now. Does this help: https://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis

Comment: I hadn't turned on ASP in the "Turn Windows features on or off".  Once I did this it worked.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - You should offer that comment as an answer, as it solved the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable ASP classic in IIS7.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072048/how-to-enable-asp-classic-in-iis7-5)

Comment: @john What they should do is search first, realise this isn't the first time someone has asked about Classic ASP setup on IIS and flagged it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

It's not enabled by default because of security reasons. The IIS server comes 'pre-secured' now. Does this help

https://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis

Summary:

Classic ASP Not Installed by Default on IIS 7.0 and above

When adding IIS using the server roles and features wizard, make sure you tick 'asp' and 'isapi extensions'