# unable to successfuly launch classic ASP app in IIS

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I have been looking into this issue for the last 2 days. I've looked through many of similar questions and I've done everything that has been shows as an answer, yet I still am not able to properly use my class .asp application.

I am able to launch my web app - the first page is the LOGIN page, i enter the credentials (that work) click OK then it loads and I get the following error:

> An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please
>   contact the system administrator. If you are the system administrator
>   please click here to find out more about this error.

The click HERE link is this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis

It's telling me that I don't have classic ASP Installed - so I followed the directions, and additionally looked at other similar questions on SO and did exactly that:
[image]

SO that's good, next I came across another question - [How to enable ASP classic in IIS7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072048/how-to-enable-asp-classic-in-iis7-5)

and here's what I did:

> So to resolve this issue, go to the website you want to add your
>   application to, then double click on Handler Mappings. Click "Add
>   Script Map" and enter in the following information:
>
> RequestPath: *.asp Executable: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\asp.dll
>   Name: Classic ASP (this can be anything you want it to be)

Like so:

[image]

YET, I'm still having the same issue. I added a NEW SITE in IIS, then added the directory for my Classic .ASP File. To launch it I click START on the right hand side like so:

[image]

I click on BROWSE and it opens the LOGIN page, again the login page opens up properly and I see in the URL bar is just shows : `https://localhost/` , now once I click the OK button to log in, it's suppose to do Response.Redirect test.asp in which case it shows: `https://localhost/test.asp`

I apologize for the crazy long question but I wanted to exhaust all options before posting this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: PER Daniel, I configued an error setting to SEND ERROR TO BROWSER and here is what I received:

> Response object error 'ASP 0251 : 80004005'
>
> Response Buffer Limit Exceeded
>
> /Test.asp, line 0
>
> Execution of the ASP page caused the Response Buffer to exceed its
>   configured limit.

Comment: First, remove "friendly http error message" from IE, and check "Send error to browser".  You'll see real error message.

Comment: Error: ther eis a problem with this websites security certificate. The security certificate presents by this website was no issues by trusted certificate authority. if I click on "Contineut to this website (not recommended) again it shows me the LOGIN page and again it gives me the same generic error when I try to log in.

Comment: @DanielBlais okay I configued IIS to send error to Browser and please look at the edit what it actually showed.

Comment: I got it - i updated the Response Buffer Limit to: 40194304 and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remove "friendly http error message" from IE, and check "Send error to browser". You'll see real error message.

Answer (score 0):

ASP normally buffers the entire page, and only outputs after the entire page is generated in the buffer. However, the buffer has a finite size — about 4MB if memory serves. It appears you have a *really* large page here and it’s choking on it.

So what you have to do is output the buffer as you go. Write, say, 500 lines, and then write out the buffer using `Response.Flush`

For example, let's say I'm looping through a really large number of records and outputting them to the page.  I can iterate x on each record, and then do the following at the end of the loop:

```
if x >= 500 then
    x = 0
    Response.Flush
end if
```

Comment: I just changed the Response Buffer Limit to 40mb and haven't had any issues.

Comment: updated answer with code.  Using a really large buffer works if you can handle the load, but dumping the buffer is more resource-friendly!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The ASP app i'm working on is not that big. Increasing the Response Buffer Limit to 40mb did the job.